# Does Selenium implicit wait always take the entire wait time or can it finish sooner?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does Selenium implicit wait always take the entire wait time or can it finish sooner?  If I set the implicit wait to 10 seconds, could a call to .findElement finish in a few seconds or would it always take the entire 10 seconds?

[This page](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.com/2013/10/webdriver-implicit-and-explicit-wait.html) implies that it waits the full 10 seconds, which is very confusing because its not what the javadoc implies.

The following code comment from WebDriver.java implies that its a polling action which can finish sooner than the implicit timeout is defined at.  BUT, **the last sentence in the comment really throws a wrench into that belief** and makes me not totally sure about it.  If it is actually polling, then how would it "adversely affect test time", since it wouldn't go the entire implicit wait duration?

```
/**
 *  from WebDriver.java
 * Specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if
 * it is not immediately present.
 * <p/>
 * When searching for a single element, the driver should poll the page until the 
 * element has been found, or this timeout expires before throwing a 
 * {@link NoSuchElementException}. When searching for multiple elements, the driver 
 * should poll the page until at least one element has been found or this timeout has
 * expired.
 * <p/>
 * Increasing the implicit wait timeout should be used judiciously as it will have an 
 * adverse effect on test run time, especially when used with slower location 
 * strategies like XPath.
 * 
 * @param time The amount of time to wait.
 * @param unit The unit of measure for {@code time}.
 * @return A self reference.
 */
Timeouts implicitlyWait(long time, TimeUnit unit);
```

Also, if anyone can provide information on how often the default "polling" occurs?

Comment: Looking back on this question, hind sight is 20/20 since what i posted does in fact seem like it should have answered itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can finish once it was able to find the element. If not it does throws the error and stops. The poll time is again very specific to the driver implementation ( not Java bindings , but the driver part, example: FireFox extension, Safari Extension etc.)

As I have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851122/where-is-the-implementation-for-the-webelement-isdisplayed-method-in-selenium/27852528#27852528), these are very specific to the driver implementation. All driver related calls goes via `execute` method.

I'm putting up the gist over of the `execute` method (you can find the full source [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java#L562)):

```
protected Response execute(String driverCommand, Map<String, ?> parameters) {
    Command command = new Command(sessionId, driverCommand, parameters);
    Response response;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String currentName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    Thread.currentThread().setName(
        String.format("Forwarding %s on session %s to remote", driverCommand, sessionId));
    try {
      log(sessionId, command.getName(), command, When.BEFORE);
      response = executor.execute(command);
      log(sessionId, command.getName(), command, When.AFTER);

      if (response == null) {
        return null;
      }
      //other codes 
}
```

The line:

```
response = executor.execute(command);
```

says the whole story. `executor` is of type `CommandExecutor`, so all calls goes to the specific driver class like `ChromeCommandExecutor,SafariDriverCommandExecutor`, which has their own handling.

So the polling is upto the driver implementation.

If you want to specify the polling time, then you should probably start using [Explicit Waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits).

Comment: Ah.. that makes sense that there is not one definitive answer on the polling period if it is driver specific.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the code comment:

```
 * When searching for a single element, the driver should poll the page until the 
 * element has been found, or this timeout expires before throwing a 
 * {@link NoSuchElementException}.
```

Its going to wait till that element present, or timeout occurs.

For example, If you set Implicit wait as 10 seconds,  `.findElement` is going to wait maximum of 10 seconds for that element. Suppose that element available in the DOM in 5 seconds, then it will come out of "wait" and start executing next step.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking for a reference showing proof that this answer is the case.  I looked in the Selenium source code but its tough to find without having an IDE.  Do you know what the polling period is?  I'm not the one that downvoted, but I upvoted to offset it.

Comment: I believe, polling period is 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Looks like another person downvoted.  I don't understand why people downvote helpful posts.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge polling period is not 0.5 seconds with implicit wait. It is the case with explicit wait. Explicit wait polls the DOM every 500ms. Implicit wait, if the element is not found on page load waits for the specified time and then checks again after time is run out. If not found it throws an error