# Where is the implementation for the WebElement.isDisplayed() method in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

Where is the implementation of the `WebElement.isDisplayed()` method?   The `WebElement`.java class is an interface that creates the contract for a `isDisplayed()` method but I cannot find source code that shows how it works.   Does anyone know how I can find it?    I know about dom.js  and I can see how all the methods in `ExpectedConditions`.java all work, but I can't find the source code implementation (in `Java`) of what we call `element.isDisplayed()` .

I think that to truly understand how `ExpectedConditions` works, I need to know the workings of the underlying  `isDisplayed()` method.   I can't figure out how it eventually calls the `bot.dom.isInteractable`  method in `dom.js` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation details are specific to the driver.

But you can find the `isDisplayed` method over here in `RemoteWebElement`. All `WebElement` methods are been implemented over [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.35.0/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.java#RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed%28%29).

The method looks like this:

```
public boolean isDisplayed() {
    Object value = execute(DriverCommand.IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED, ImmutableMap.of("id", id))        .getValue();
    try {
          return (Boolean) value;
    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
      throw new WebDriverException("Returned value cannot be converted to Boolean: " + value, ex);    
   }  
}
```

And the line:

```
execute(DriverCommand.IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED, ImmutableMap.of("id", id))
```

is purely driver specific, as each driver has its own implementation of handling this operation `IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED`.

For example the `SafariDriver`, which works with extensions, hence you can find the implementation on the extension side, which can be found [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/safari-driver)