# Verify element is not displayed

Tags: java, selenium

I want to check that an element is not displayed. I have written the following code :

```
public boolean verifyelementNotDisplayed() {
        try
            {
               if(element("element").isDisplayed())
                   return false;
                   else
                 {
                     logMessage("element not displayed");
                  return true;
                 }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }

    }
```

But my test fails.

Comment: Post your "isDisplayed" method with all necessary information pls

Comment: isDisplayed() is an inbuilt function in selenium.

Comment: please provide the code for your test, and tell us where exactly your test fails (does this method return false even though you expect true? what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked

```
        public boolean verifyNoelement() {
            try
            {
               if(element("element").isDisplayed())
               {
               return false;
               }
               return false;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                 logMessage("No element displayed");
                return true;
            }


        }
```

Comment: This will not return false if the method is displayed this will return false everytime because you have a semicolon after your if sentence

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
public boolean verifyelementNotDisplayed() {
    try{
       return(!element("element").isDisplayed());
    catch(Exception e){
       return false;
    }
}
```

And have a look at the is displayed method:

[How does Selenium WebDriver's isDisplayed() method work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062372/how-does-selenium-webdrivers-isdisplayed-method-work)

or:

[Where is the implementation for the WebElement.isDisplayed() method in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851122/where-is-the-implementation-for-the-webelement-isdisplayed-method-in-selenium)