# Python & Selenium: Difference between driver.implicitly_wait() and time.sleep()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sleep, implicitwait

Yes, I know both are used to wait for some specified time.

**Selenium:**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

**Python:**

```
import time
time.sleep(10)
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: `time.sleep()` will halt your code execution on that line, but selenium `implicitly_wait()` is just a setting for the driver. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831757/does-selenium-implicit-wait-always-take-the-entire-wait-time-or-can-it-finish-so)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- time.sleep(10) pauses code execution exactly 10 seconds.
- driver.implicitly_wait(10) waits maximum 10 seconds for element's presence. If it is found after 2 seconds then code execution will be continued without wait for more 8 seconds.

Answer (score 29):

### time.sleep(secs)

> [**`time.sleep(secs)`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) suspends the execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)

---

### implicitly_wait(time_to_wait)

[implicitly_wait(time_to_wait)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.implicitly_wait) is to specify the amount of time the *WebDriver* instance i.e. the *driver* should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) in-terms of `SECONDS` when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is **0** which means the `driver` when finds an instruction to find an element or elements, the search starts and results are available on immediate basis.

In this case, after a fresh loading of a webpage an element or elements may be / may not be found on an immediate search. So your *Automation Script* may be facing any of these exceptions:

- [`NoSuchElementException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException)
- [`TimeoutException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException)
- [`ElementNotVisibleException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException)
- [`ElementNotSelectableException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotSelectableException)
- [`ElementClickInterceptedException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException)
- [`ElementNotInteractableException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException)

Hence we introduce **ImplicitWait**. By introducing *ImplicitWait* the *driver* will poll the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) until the element has been found for the configured amount of time looking out for the element or elements before throwing a [`NoSuchElementException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException). By that time the element or elements for which you had been looking for may be available in the *HTML DOM*. As in your code you have already set *ImplicitWait* to a value of **10** seconds, the *driver* will poll the *HTML DOM* for **10** seconds.

You can find a detailed discussion in [Using implicit wait in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium)

Comment: Hi, @undetected_Selenium, can you confirm this answer by Fiona , if it is True?
`driver.implicitly_wait(10) waits maximum 10 seconds for element's presence. If it is found after 2 seconds then code execution will be continued without wait for more 8 seconds.` Thanks

Comment: @undetected Selenium, thank you for the comprehensive advice. We do need the set the Implicit Wait only once? Right now, I keep using `WebDriverWait(self.driver, MAX_WAIT).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable()` for every element I want to click on. Can all those be replaced with one call to driver.implicitly_wait?

Answer (score 3):

When we use implicit wait in test script it is declared globally and it will automatically get applied to all the elements on that script and for example in java if you use implicit wait.  --> driver. manage().timeouts().implictwait(10,timeunit.seconds);. this code will wait for the element to be present in DOM until then it will wait once element gets visible execution will get continue. during the time of hold script execution is stopped.

In thread.sleep(1000) in this case script will get hold for 1000ms no matter if element gets visible on dom at 500ms it will stay at this point till 1000 ms.

Thread.sleep() is a static wait which holds script duration for fixed number of time. Where as implicit wait will hld the script execution until element gets visible in DOM.

Hope this helps!